# DateTime parsing error while parsing dd/MM/yyyy format. String was not recognized as valid datetime

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I create a string using values from certain page elements in my web user control as below

```
string bookingdate = ddlDate.SelectedItem.Text 
                       + "/" + ddlMonth.SelectedValue + "/" 
                       + ddlMonth.SelectedItem.Text.Substring(4, 2);
```

and getting "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime." error on the following line

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ArrivalDate", SqlDbType.DateTime)).Value = 
    DateTime.ParseExact(bookingdate, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

How can I alter the value of this string "bookingdate" to troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: What is the value of `bookingdate` exactly?

Comment: you can use TryParseExact instead of ParseExact http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx

Comment: This should be the `yyyy` year part: `ddlMonth.SelectedItem.Text.Substring(4, 2);` ?

Comment: To answer your alert  question: use the debugger instead.

Comment: The value of bookingdate is likely to be e.g. "15/09/2013". I also tried TryParseExact but still getting the same error. I m using sql server 2005

Comment: @Dev see my answer below

Comment: @TimSchmelter the form can be seen at http://www.thetyndruminn.co.uk/bookonline.aspx and the year value is like to be 13 or 14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So `ddlMonth` contains items in this format (you posted [the link](http://www.thetyndruminn.co.uk/bookonline.aspx) to your page):

```
<option value="08">Aug 14</option>
```

Now you're trying to extract the month and year part from it:

```
ddlMonth.SelectedValue + "/" + ddlMonth.SelectedItem.Text.Substring(4, 2)
```

Your format string is this: `dd/MM/yyyy`

Do you already see the problem? The format string expects four digits for the year.

Instead use this format string: `dd/MM/yy`

```
DateTime.ParseExact(bookingdate, "dd/MM/yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

As I can understand you need `Indian Date Format` that is `dd/mm/yyyy`. So in your code, pass parameter as string and in sql handle it using `Convert(date,Convert(datetime,@ArrivalDate,103))`. Use `date` as your datatype if you need only date and is on `Sql 2008 or above` otherwise

```
Convert(datetime,@ArrivalDate,103) and leave your datatype as datetime
```

In cs:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ArrivalDate", bookingdate);
```

Comment: I have datetime column in my database and It be a big design change to change the datatype

Comment: @Dev... Let it remain datetime, you have to change the SP parameter and in the code as I answered and you are done.